Can an ashkenazi Jew eat on dishes at a sephardi house on Pesach?
If someone follows ashkenazi customs and is invited by a sephardi family to eat at their house, is he allowed to eat off their dishes?
In my understanding, sephardim are allowed to kasher the plates and use same glass dishes for both meat and dairy. Both practices are not permitted for ashkenazi Jews. Can an ashkenazi Jew eat from a glass plate in a sephardi house, even if all their food is kosher for Passover according to sephardi customs?

For glass plates, Sephardim don't require kashering or anything. Just clean them off, they don't absorb at all.

Ashkenazim hold that glass should be treated as if it can absorb flavor, but it can't actually treif up your food. I thought you were asking about if they serve kitniyos, or serve you a potato cooked in a metal pot that was used to cook rice one hour earlier.

@Shalom I know, so my question is if you are ashkenazi are you allowed to eat at one of those plates?

I've had people eat at my house, after asking a posek in Gateshead fwiw

In a halacha class I was in I remember learning that when eating at someone's house you can rely on their mesorah for kashrus. This means even eating a species you might not eat in your home as long as you are a guest you rely on the mesorah of that family. So while there could be an argument for avoiding doing so once you are eating in their home you wouldn't say we'll eat this but not that or eat off this plate but not that plate.

Personally, I refrain from eating by my Sepharadi friends on Pesach, but it permissible according to most mainstream poskim, especially in Israel

Why is this being asked specifically as regards Pesah? If this is a problem, it's a problem all year long. And if it is not a problem, then Pesah doesn't cause it to be one. Please clarify.

@Deuteronomy many Ashkenazim do kasher glass but not for pesach. And many kashrut rules are stricter on pesach than at other times.

https://jewishlink.news/eating-out-during-pesach-ashkenazim-at-the-homes-of-sephardim/ https://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/may-an-ashkenazi-eat-at-a-sephardis-home-on-pesach/2019/04/18/
